# In PartiQL, Can you filter the table based on if a column which contains a list of maps contains something in one of the maps?

Tags: amazon-web-services, partiql

I want to be able to see if this list of maps contains a certain string.

I have tried using the 'contains' function a few different ways
select * from "TABLE.NAME" where contains ("COLUMN_NAME", 'stringIWantToSearchFor')
select * from "TABLE_NME" WHERE contains ("COLUMN_NAME.MAP_ATTRIBUTE_NAME", 'stringIWantToSearchFor')

these both return no results. I would be satisfied with a way to temporarily turn the list into a string and search that way, or a way to filter directly.